# Itô diffusion and Kolmogorov backward and forward equations

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For the Kolmogorov backward and forward (aka Fokker-Planck) equations to hold, and also for the Feynman-Kac formula, is it necessary for the terms in the stochastic differential equation
$$
dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t
$$
to be time-independent
$$
dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t
$$
or not? My impression is that the requirement is markovity, and thus one often finds the theorems in terms of Itô's diffusions, which are always Markov processes.